# Neo4j Delete All Nodes and Relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to delete all nodes and relationships.

I run `MATCH ()-[r]-() DELETE r` to delete all the relationships.

Then, I run `MATCH (n) DELETE n` to delete all the nodes. It does delete all the nodes, but the problem is that it also gives me this error:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.Transaction.TransactionCommitFailed
Unable to complete transaction.
```

How do I delete all nodes and relationships with getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

To delete all nodes and all relationships, I do DETACH DELETE

> Reference:
> https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/delete/#delete-delete-all-nodes-and-relationships

```
 MATCH (n)
 DETACH DELETE n;
```

If nothing works, then rename (or remove) your neo4j data folder and restart your server.

<HOME_NEO4j>/data/data/transactions/neo4j

Comment: That does delete everything, but still gives me the error I have in my question.

Comment: Your delete is not the same with my answer.  If nothing works for you then remove or rename the data folder in neo4j. This will reset your database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database is hitting an OOM Exception.
As stated in [Large Delete Transaction Best Practices in Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/large-delete-transaction-best-practices-in-neo4j/)

```
If you need to delete some large number of objects from the graph, one needs to be mindful of the not building up such a large single transaction such that a Java OUT OF HEAP Error will be encountered.
```

1. Delete all constraints and indexes

   CALL apoc.schema.assert({},{},true);
2. Batch delete with CALL {} IN TRANSACTIONS syntax or apoc.periodic.iterate:

> ```
> MATCH (n:Foo) where n.foo='bar'
> CALL { WITH n
> DETACH DELETE n
> } IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS;
> ```

OR

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (n) RETURN n",
"DETACH DELETE n",
{batchSize:10000, parallel:false})
```